# PHP setting variables for variables in a webpage

Tags: php

I've been making a webpage with php and html following [this tutorial](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/). I was trying to setup a template where I could set various variables like title of the page, content, etc. But I've been running into some trouble getting things to set properly.

In my index page I have php start like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
include('includes/meta.php');
$md = new metadata();
$md->setTitle("HELLOOOO");
?> 
...<!-- rest of html -->
```

then in my Metadata class in meta.php (contains the  HTML):

```
<?php

class metadata
{
    private $title = "default";
    public function setTitle($title) { $this->title = $title; }
    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }


}
 ?>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
         <?php $md = new metadata();
             echo $md->getTitle();?>
    </title>
```

But "default" is always echoed for the title.

**How can I properly set variables in separate classes / files? And what is the best convention of accomplishing this?**

Comment: I'd say the original problem is to follow that tutorial. Take some other one, that one does not give good directions for you. The PHP manual btw. has a nice section showing the basics for template variabnles: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: You can not create two object of a class that is first thing. 'cuz you have created object in meta.php file and also in your index.php by same name in which meta.php is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a singleton, because when you do `new metadata();`, you're creating a new object, when in fact you want the one to reference the one that was created first.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
class metadata
{
    private $title = "default";
    private function __construct() {} // Private constructor

    private static $instance = null;
    public static function getInstance() {
       if( self::$instance == null) { 
           self::$instance = new metadata();
       }
       return self::$instance;
    }
    public function setTitle($title) { $this->title = $title; }
    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
}
```

Now, you need to do:

```
$md = metadata::getInstance();
```

To get an object of the metadata class.

[See it work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cru7SF)

Comment: I can't get it to work for some reason. I put the new functions in meta.php and then tried to setTitle() from index.php but it just echos default for title. Can't figure out what I'm missing. I see it working codepad. Do I have to extend the class in index.php ?

Comment: nm, I had a stupid mistake per usual, haha. Thanks this was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton isn't enough because the file declaring the class also contains the HTML to output.
So two solutions:

You split class definition and html output in two different files. The metadata class should be a singleton to not rely on how do you call the variable.

You encapsulate HTML output into a method of your class and call this method when you want. The metadata class could be a singleton but that's not mandatory in this case.